# Thin alkyd paint for spraying

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, spraypainting

I want to paint over factory finished kitchen cabinets.

I plan to sand them and brush primer with oil based paint.

I plan to use an alkyd paint I was told will make a nice finish.

Home Depot warns me to use only latex in their rental sprayer.

What can I thin the alkyd paint with to safely use in the sprayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### YOU DON'T!!!

Do not put alkyd (oil) paints in a sprayer not made for them.  They will destroy the seals.  The act will be detected.  That is a very expensive way to buy a commercial grade latex paint sprayer that only works on latex paint and is now ruined.

You'll need to buy a proper spray gun made for aklyds, epoxies, LPUs and the like. I have been delighted with [this little guy](http://amzn.to/2y22wOn), I run it at 10-20 pounds and it works great.

Honestly unless you are well practiced in the art of spraying, you may be better off sticking to brush.   Google "$50 Rustoleum paint job" for tactics to get near-spray-finish out of common alkyd paints.

P.S. there is nothing lowly or amateur about brushing. I do my best work brushing $300/gal. aircraft grade LPUs (because the stuff is extremely toxic to spray, whereas with brush, you only need gloves).